# passing a dynamic variable to act as object key

Tags: javascript, function, javascript-objects

I have a helper function that I want to accept a few parameters and update an object. The idea is to cal the function and pass the key I want to access (dynamic) and the new value for that key.

```
export function updateObject(id, key, value, arrayOfObjects) {
  const arr = [...arrayOfObjects];
  const index = arrayOfObjects.findIndex((x) => x.id === id);
  arr[index].key = value;
  return arr;
}
```

The issue is `arr[index].key = value;` isn't accessing the `key` value I'm passing as a parameter. It's just assuming that `arr[index]` has a key called `key`.

This doesn't help as I want this to be able to edit any key for all objects based on what key we pass as a parameter when calling the function. For example:

```
updateObject(2, "name", "John")
updateObject(2, "age", "32")
```

This should be able to use the same function rather than hardcoding different functions for different keys. Is there a better way to do this? If I have the right idea, how can allow the key (parameter) to work dynamically?

Comment: arr[index][key]

Comment: Interesting. Why exactly does this work? Just wondering the reasons

Comment: with square brackets you can do dynamic stuff. with the dot it tries to access exact field. also u need square bracket if u have weird field names like fields containing spaces

Comment: `a.key` is accessing the property called `key` on object `a`, whereas `a[key]` is accessing the property whose name is the value of the variable `key`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/accessing-an-object-property-with-a-dynamically-computed-name

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `find` and get the object in which you intend to change the `key`

```
export function updateObject(id, key, value, arrayOfObjects) {
  const arr = arrayOfObjects.find((x) => x.id === id);
  arr[key] = value;
  return arr;
}
```

Comment: I'm setting a react state though with this return so don't i need to deconstruct and reconstruct the array? Or I can just edit the array coming in and return that edited array.